# Best practice to keep an up to date Azure SDK in a team environment

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

Our project depends on various Azure apis and we have an ongoing issue every-time a developer gets a new machine and the Azure SDK has updated.

When the developer installs the Azure tools we always have version mismatches.  Then if the developer installed the older version we still get build issues as the older web installer detects newer versions of products and decides not to install the older one, resulting in more build issues.

The result is just dev pain around either updating everyone at the same time or the dev on-boarding wasting lots of time.  How do others solve this issue?

Comment: We suffer from this too, and haven't found a great solution. The various OData DLL's (used by the Azure Storage libraries) are probably the worst libraries that a single company has ever produced, it causes problems on **every single** update.

Answer (score 2):

Could try putting the Azure SDK into source control so that everyone is using the same version, unfortunately they don't make it particularly easy.  Azure installs to a fixed path, sets some registry keys and creates a .targets file in your MSBuild extensions.

An idea proposed here: [using azure SDK without installing](http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/12/19/build-azure-projects-without-installing-the-azure-sdk-on-your-build-server/), suggests building your own Nuget package and using that setup to install the SDK.

Comment: FYI Several parts of the SDK are already available from Microsoft as Nuget packages, including storage and service bus (and others). Several downloadable versions of each...